# How to convert UTF-8 hex value to char in Rust?

Tags: rust, unicode

I have a hex value of a Unicode character. How can I convert it to `char`in Rust?

`char::from_u32()` didn't work because `char` didn't seem to contain a hex value:

```rust
fn main() {
    let code_point: u32 = 0xf09f8cb8; //emoji ''
    println!("{}", code_point); //=> 4036988088

    let c = '';
    println!("{}", c as u32); //=> 127800 (not 4036988088)
}
```

Comment: You seem to mix up UTF-8 and code points. They are different things. "f09f8cb8" is UTF-8 for this character but it makes no sense to interpret it as u32. It is a sequence of bytes. 127800 is the code point which is a single number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code treats the hex values as a Unicode code point, but they're actually the emoji's UTF-8 encoding. To decode it, store the bytes as a byte string and call [`std::str::from_utf8`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/str/fn.from_utf8.html).

```
let bytes: &[u8] = b"\xf0\x9f\x8c\xb8";
let string: &str = std::str::from_utf8(bytes)?;
println!("{}", string);
```

Output:

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=af33a991a7b9cd60dafbba5ac68dd518)

Answer (score 6):

As others have pointed out, the `u32` value is not a code point, but is a UTF-8 byte sequence when viewed as big-endian.

You can convert this value to a string by combining `u32::to_be_bytes()` with `std::str::from_utf8()`:

```
fn main() {
    let utf8_u32: u32 = 0xf09f8cb8;
    let utf8_bytes = utf8_u32.to_be_bytes();
    let s = std::str::from_utf8(&utf8_bytes);
    
    assert_eq!(s, Ok(""));
}
```